# static const in classes

Tags: c++

I think is an old question but I don't get it.

I have a header routines.h, its functions file routines.cpp and the main file main.cpp.

In the header there is:

```
class myclass{
public:
static const double a;
void mymethod();
};

const double myclass::a=0.0;
```

The routines.cpp contains: `#include"routines.h"` and then define the methods.

main.cpp also has `#include"routines.h"`.

This setup gives a link error: a it's already defined.

```
public: static double const myclass::a" (?a148@myclass@@2NB) already defined in DBFLOWPAR2.obj
```

DBFLOWPAR2 is my main file.

If I define the methods in routines.h it works fine, but I don't like that.
What else it's possible? I don't care how the variables are defined, I just want to be able to access myclass.a and find the right value in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should define the static variable in a cpp file.
Move,

```
 const double myclass::a=0.0;
```

to your `cpp` file.

Defining `a` in header file creates a copy of the variable in each [Translation Unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c) where the header is included.

Comment: All right, thanks. First to answer so I'll accept this one. Just curious: isn't the macro `#ifndef Blala #define Blala #endif` supposed to avoid that?

Comment: @MarcoS: no. Include guards prevent the definition from appearing multiple times *in the same translation unit*. They don't stop different translation units (.cpp files) from each including the header file and hence the definition.

Comment: @MarcoS Include guards prevent a header from being included multiple times in a single translation unit. Your problem is that `const double myclass::a=0.0;` is occurring multiple times in a single _program_, which is made up of multiple translation units. I think a good exercise for understanding C++'s build model is to write some programs without using header files. Just manually 'include' the declarations and definitions you need. See what happens when you; duplicate a class definition in a single TU, put a function def in more than one TU, put a variable def in more than one TU.

Comment: Just FMI is the `=0.0` part necessary?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: No, it is not, static variables are Zero Initialized.

Comment: Since I plan to use multithread, should I remove `static` ? What is now defined as `static const` is not supposed to change amongst threads.

Comment: @MarcoS: If you plan to use a global or a static in multithreaded envrionment then you will have to provide some synchronization, if the variable will be written and read accross multiple threads. About, `const`: Once you specify `const` any attempt to change the variable after initialization will result in incorrect program.

Answer (score 3):

You have violated the [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule). Because you `#include "routines.h"` in multiple files, the definition of `myclass::a` appears in multiple files.

You must define a variable once, and only once.

Choose a convenient `.cpp` file, and move your definition to that `.cpp`.

Answer (score 1):

#### MyClass.h

```
class myclass{
public:
   static const double a;
   void mymethod();
};
```

#### MyClass.cpp

```
const double myclass::a;
```

The way you have it now, you're redefining `myclass::a` in every translation unit that includes the header.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put `const double myclass::a=0.0;` in the header file, otherwise each compilation unit including this file will have it's own separate variable. put this to routines.cpp.